# Ubuntu Randomly going off

Tags: boot, 18.04, crash

From the last 1 week i'm experiencing this problem of **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS running Linux Kernel x86_64 Linux 5.0.0-31-generic** randomly switching off. It does not shut down it just goes of making the screen go black and the system dying while my 2nd drive which is an HDD making a "keech" sound.This happens while booting also many times when the company logo shows(within 1-2 sec of boot up). I mostly shut the lid of my laptop after i'm done and it goes to sleep. This random switching off happens in sleep mode also. It really getting irritating at this point.***I'm using a Lenovo E41-15 laptop.***[image: log files]

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue to me; most devices shutdown down via a signal sent to PSU that kills power (ie. no OS shutdown can occur as power just goes off) by design if certain error conditions are detected; done to prevent warranty claims. On enterprise/better hardware you can search hardware logs and find clues to the cause for shutdown; but that's box specific (lower end devices don't record these details; and some conditions such as cpu too hot can't be recorded by main cpu; so box needs secondary logging chips to do it found usually in servers)  *ps: I don't know your device*

Comment: I've added log files do they show any errors ??

Comment: I was talking hardware log files, ie. enter BIOS & look up logs of startup day/time, shutdown day/time, power supply issues (voltage alerts, temperature alerts etc)... I suspect your device doesn't include this as more consumer grade